# Azure pipeline doesn't deploy on my onprem Environment target but on an Azure one

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Here is my configuration I use to build and deploy my pipeline:

```
stages:
- stage: BuildAndPush
  displayName: Build Docker Image
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  [...]
    
- stage: Deployment
  displayName: Deployment
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment:
    displayName: Deploy on ${{variables.environment}} environment
    environment: ${{variables.environment}}
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: List Artifacts
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: echo "HOSTNAME= $HOSTNAME"
```

Regarding my Environment, my resource gets never deployed:

[image: Environment - Resources]
[image: Environment - Deployments]

I expect my `Deploymment` stage to run on my onprem VM directly however it doesn't.
How can I change this behavior? As today all deployment pipeline are running on a hosted Azure VM instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both to putting me on the good tracks.

Solution was actually simpler than I thought, simply precise on which resource name you want to deploy by extending the `environment` part:

```
  jobs:
  - deployment:
    displayName: Deploy on ${{variables.environment}} environment
    environment: 
      name: ${{variables.environment}}
      resourceName: ${{parameters.vmToDeploy}} ## HERE !!!
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the below solution,

If the stage need to run in an on premise PC first of all need to add the Self-Hosted Agents (These are created and managed by the Customer) in Azure DevOps, The instruction in the below link,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

After add the Self-Hosted Agents define the pool in stage,

```
stage: Deployment
  displayName: Deployment
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment:
    displayName: Deploy on ${{variables.environment}} environment
    environment: ${{variables.environment}}
    **pool:
      vmImage: 'Your-Agent-Name'**
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: List Artifacts
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: echo "HOSTNAME= $HOSTNAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating self-hosted agents(Windows or Linux) in Azure DevOps would be best. Self-hosted agents basically are build machines you use to run the pipeline.
Specify the self-hosted agent in the YAML pipeline.

Note: If you're building a docker image, you need to install docker on the agent.

STEPS:

- Go to your project settings on Azure DevOps, In the pipeline section,
  create a self-hosted agent pool.
- Inside the agent pool, click on New Agent to create a new
  agent.(Choose Windows, Linux or Mac).
- Additionally, install docker in the agent
- After creating the agent, specify the agent pool name in your
  pipeline